# Launching multiple Google searches in separate iframes - get blocked by Google for automating searches?

Tags: html, search, iframe, automation

Using simple HTML and Ruby on Rails (could have used javascript too), I have written a search such that once I hit submit will launch multiple search results (each varied slightly) to be shown in a new "search results" page, consisting of multiple iframes, each with a different search inside them:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/search?q=<%= @search1.term %>"> </iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/search?q=<%= @search2.term %>"> </iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/search?q=<%= @search3.term %>"> </iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/search?q=<%= @search4.term %>"> </iframe>
```

This used to work, but recently stopped working.  All I see now is a blank page within the iframe.  If I use Amazon instead of Google, it works. I thought it might be because I got blocked by Google for "automating" searches. But even with just 1 iframe, it still does not work.

Any ideas anyone?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's with the "#&"?  Is that a funky API thing?  Usually the ampersand is used to delimit multiple GET variables.  You're only passing on variable...  You sure you didn't mean:

`https://www.google.com/search?q=<%= @search1.term %>`

Have you tried the url in a regular old browser to make sure you're automating a valid string?

Comment: Yeah that was funky. I changed it to the correct format (as you advised), but it still not working. I still get blank pages.  The URL's are working by themselves within a new browser tab.

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing the same issue, Ubuntu 10.04, Firefox 3.6.23

If I right-click and "view page source" then it looks fine. But if I right-click one of the iframes and "view frame source" then I see just a single line of html producing a blank page.

I think it is the X-Frame-Options specified by Google in the results page. Google is (I surmise) specifying that the results are not to be embedded in an iframe, and Firefox is respecting that by substituting a blank iframe.

So there isn't really any solution : if Google don't want their results in an iframe, they have the right to say so.

Comment: Sorry, I realise that should have been a comment not an answer.

Comment: Except I don't know how to do that - how can I comment on a question? There is no "comment" button.

Comment: Maybe You have not enough rank to comment in question.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=70345